# Finding the average value of a function over a region $R$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Consider the integral $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x^2}^{4} f(x,y) dydx$$
>
> Find the average value of $f(x,y)=xe^{y^2}$ on the region $R$.

So I calculated the area by doing $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x^2}^{4} dy dx=\frac{16}{3}$$

I'm pretty sure this value is correct. Then to find the average value I need to do:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x^2}^{4} xe^{y^2}dy dx$$

I'm just confused on what I should get as the answer.

Starting with the first integral $$\int_{x^2}^{4}xe^{y^2}dy=\frac{xe^{y^2}}{2y}\Bigg|_{x^2}^{4}=\frac{xe^{16}}{8}-\frac{xe^{x^4}}{2x^2}$$

Then I need to do the outer integral so I have:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{xe^{16}}{8}-\frac{xe^{x^4}}{2x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{xe^{16}}{8} dx - \int_{0}^{2}\frac{xe^{x^4}}{2x^2}dx$$

The left integral is easy to evaluate as $\frac{e^{16}}{4}$

I'm having trouble with the right integral. When I put it into an online calculator, I get $\frac{Ei(x^4)}{8}+C$. But my professor said there was an easy numerical solution to this. So I'm not sure what to do. The online calculator does a u-sub so that $u=x^4$ and then the integral simplifies to $\int \frac{e^u}{u}du$ and then it says this is a special exponential integral.

Comment: You integrated incorrectly $e^{y^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is $\int e^{y^2}dy\neq\frac1{2y}e^{y^2}$ when you tried to evaluate the $y$ integral. In fact, $ e^{y^2}$ does not have an elementary anti-derivative, therefore the key is to change the integration order from $dydx$ to $dxdy$. Namely,
$$\int_0^2\int_{x^2}^4xe^{y^2}dydx=\int_0^4\int_0^{\sqrt y}xe^{y^2}dxdy=\frac12\int_0^4ye^{y^2}dy\overset{u=y^2}{=}\frac14\int_0^{16}e^udu=\frac14(e^{16}-1).$$
To see why $\int_0^2\int_{x^2}^4=\int_0^4\int_0^{\sqrt y}$, you could plot the integration area in the $xy$-plane.